# Regex exclude brackets

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have the following regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9](est)[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Test string:

```
this is a test [est+where] esterius
```

it should only highlight the first "est". Sadly the bracket [ and the + symbol is also matched. But I want only my word "est" to be matched if the character before and after is non-alphabetical and not numeric

Comment: You need no lookarounds, just access the capture group (`match.Groups[1].Value`)

Comment: I agree with @WiktorStribiżew You don't need lookarounds for this at all. Your capture group already contains exactly what you need. I honestly think the accepted answer below is overkill. Not to mention that look behinds are not supported in all regex flavors, so if you ever have to port to JavaScript, the below doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])est(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

Which basically match something without including it in the resulting match.

Comment: Thanks I also didn't know it